# Convert ISO8601 DateTime String to Date in Swift

Tags: swift, datetime, iso8601

I am attempting to convert a string in ISO8601 format that includes the timezone offset (in this case, Eastern Time Zone) into a date but the conversion returns a nil value:

```swift
func utcStringToLocalDate(dateString: String) -> Date? {        
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"

    let convertedDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
                
    return convertedDate
}
```

calling this function like so:

```swift
utcStringToLocalDate(dateString: "2020-07-29T12:00:00-05:00")
```

will return a nil value

I also tried

```swift
func utcStringToLocalDate(dateString: String) -> Date? {
    let iso8601Formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    iso8601Formatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime,
                                      .withDashSeparatorInDate,
                                      .withFullDate,
                                      .withColonSeparatorInTimeZone]

    let convertedDate = iso8601Formatter.date(from: dateString)
  }
```

but there was no joy either, it also returned nil

What is the proper approach or format that will return an ISO 8601 date such as *2020-07-29T12:00:00-05:00* or *2020-07-29T12:00:00-0500*?

Comment: Tip with DateFormatters: Do the reverse: Date => String, instead of String from Date, with the format you *think* is correct. Compare the output with your string, you'll see the difference. Update your format.

Comment: In this case, it would render yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ but in this case, the letter "Z" is a zone designator for zero offset, a.k.a. UTC, GMT, Zulu time and specifically, I am trying to render the date with the Eastern time zone, the reason for the "-5:00"